# How fetch_feed() works?

Tags: rss, feed

I would like to know that how `fetch_feed()` works extactly?

From the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed#Notes):

> `fetch_feed()` caches results for 12 hours by default.

That means if I use `fetch_feed( 'howtogeek.com' )`, it reads the RSS feeds from howtogeek at first, it will save the result for 12 hours.

Otherwise what is the meaning of *caches results for 12 hours by default.*?

Comment: What other meaning could that be? I don't really get your question.

Comment: The answer is **yes** else what do you want to know ?

Comment: @toscho I think the question is **when** it is read/cached (based on first visit or at a specific time maybe...)

Comment: If you meant the "by default", then it's 12 hours unless you return a different value from filter `wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime`.

Answer (score 2):

1 `fetch_feed` will get the feed and store it, along with the time it was fetched.

2 Every time the page with the feed is generated the time will be checked. If it is more than twelve hours ago, the feed will be reloaded. Note that this may interfere with caching plugins, who will bypass the normal page generation. Also, if the site is visited very little, the first visitor after twelve hours may still see the old feed, because WP is not particularly good at cron jobs.

3 If you don't specify another time twelve hours is the caching time for the feed. You may set up any other interval with this snipppet:

```
function feed_interval( $seconds ) {
  return 3600; // caching time in seconds
  }
add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'feed_interval' );
```

Comment: "WP is not particularly good at cron jobs" - does WP manage the cache? It pretty much delegates everything else here to SimplePie, which I assume uses some standard PHP cache under the covers?

Comment: Without claiming too much knowledge on this one: WP has its own cron process, which delegates a lot, but because it has to run on all sorts of systems it can't get all the details right. My own experience is that WP needs visits to the site to keep all processes going. If there have been no visits all night an early morning scheduled post is easily missed, for instance. This may also mean missing a scheduled refresh of the cache.